# My bash script spawns a terminal in which I want to run some commands. How do I identify the terminal by name in my script and run commands in it?

Tags: bash, xterm

I am writing a script where I run a command which is basically an application in the exec mode. It spawns another xterm terminal with a definite title everytime say, "ABCXYZ" . My purpose is then to run commands in this "ABCXYZ" window because of the environment that it has. How can I do this in my script?